# How do I create my own XML/RSS feed?

Tags: php, ruby, xml, rss, haml

I am in the process of creating my own product that acts like a Content Management System, in a way. I would like to include an RSS feed, although I'm not exactly sure how I would go about doing it.

I think it would be possible if I **iterate through each post as its being built by my Build script and append it as an item into the XML file**. Is there a more efficient or less costly way to achieve this?

I'm mainly using Ruby/Php/Haml, but I will also accept other languages (I'm willing to learn)

Comment: XML feeds are generally created on the fly. In PHP you might use SimpleXML to convert database to XML, and then print it to the screen, with an appropriate HTTP header. You can cache them if the site gets busy, but it often is not necessary. A simple version is maybe 10-15 lines of code - connect to the database, read in array, convert to XML, header, render.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - RSS builder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82872/php-rss-builder)

Comment: ^ Have a look at the library in the accepted answer of that question.

Comment: Are you generating a static site or is it served dynamically with `rails` or whatnot?

Comment: @froderik I am using the server-side (Ruby, etc.) to produce a static client-side website.

Comment: I am very happy with [nanoc](http://nanoc.ws/) for generating my blog statically. There is support for atom but I needed to tweak it a bit for rss.

Comment: @railgun - had a quick look - looks ambitious! Why do you need PHP? You could use haml and possibly also markdown with layouts instead.

Comment: @froderik i considered that but was not sure how the haml elements would go about (opening/closing tags are automatic, so how would I split it into different files?). On the other hand, I have experience with php/wordpress so it was easier for me to add php

Comment: the pragmatic approach! Often the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use a stack of x items. Every time a new post is added, you'll push it to the stack. At any given moment, you can view the stack. That's your feed.

Rails has an `after_create` mechanism to identify when a new item has been added.

For the stack, I would recommend using Redis, which is very fast.

Comment: just a suggestion, doesn't have to be.